# Arduino for loop with delay between each cycle without stopping program

Tags: c++, arduino

I am a third year student, the first arduino classes started this year - I'm having trouble executing a for loop with delay and without stopping the program. My task is to create a game similar to a dinosaur in chrome, and the problem is when I want to separate each cycle for 100ms of time for the cacti to move sideways.
Can someone help me? :)

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

// punktacja
int score = 0;
int lastScore = 0;

// czy gracz wygral?
bool won = false;

// zmienna do lcd clear po zwycięstwie
bool blocker = true;

int buttonPin = 6;
int buttonState = 0;

// Obliczanie czasu do spawnu obstacli
//unsigned long aktualnyCzas = millis();
//unsigned long zapamietanyCzas = 0;
//unsigned long roznicaCzasu = 0;

byte dino[8] = {
  0b00000,
  0b00111,
  0b00111,
  0b10110,
  0b11111,
  0b01010,
  0b01010,
  0b00000
};

byte cactus[8] = {
  0b00100,
  0b00101,
  0b10101,
  0b10101,
  0b10111,
  0b11100,
  0b00100,
  0b00000
};

byte stone[8] = {
  0b00000,
  0b00100,
  0b01110,
  0b01110,
  0b01110,
  0b11111,
  0b11111,
  0b11111
};

byte clear[8] = {
  0b00000,
  0b00000,
  0b00000,
  0b00000,
  0b00000,
  0b00000,
  0b00000,
  0b00000
};


void setup() {
  
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.setCursor(11, 0);
  lcd.print("s:");
  
  lcd.createChar(0, dino);
  lcd.createChar(1, cactus);
  lcd.createChar(2, stone);
  lcd.createChar(9, clear);
}

void loop() {
  
  //Obliczanie czasu
  //aktualnyCzas = millis();
  
  // Odczyt z guzika
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  //Główna pętla gry
  if(won == false)  
  {
    // Spawn kamieni
    if(lastScore < score - 5)
    {
      lastScore = score;
      for(int i = 15; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            SpawnStone(i);
            wait(100);
        }
    }
      
    // Punktacja
    score = millis() / 100;
    lcd.setCursor(13, 0);
    lcd.print(score);
    
    if(buttonState == HIGH)
    {
      JumpDino();

    }
    else if (buttonState == LOW)
    {
      SpawnDino();
    }
  }
  
  //LCD Clear po wygranej
  
  if(score == 1000 && blocker == true)
  {
    blocker = false;
    lcd.clear();
  }
  
  //Informacja o zwycięstwie
  
  if(score > 999)
  {
    won = true;
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("YOU WON!");
    return;
  }
}

void SpawnDino()
{
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.write(byte(0));
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.write(byte(9));
}

void JumpDino()
{
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.write(byte(0));
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.write(byte(9));
}

int SpawnStone(int i)
{
    lcd.setCursor(i,1);
    lcd.write(byte(2));
    lcd.setCursor(i+1,1);
    lcd.write(byte(9));
}

void wait(long duration)
{
    int wait = 0;
    long last = millis();
    while (wait == 0)
    {
        long now = millis();

        if (now - last >= duration) 
        { wait = 1;}
        else {}
    }
}
```

@Edit

I tried this:

```
int SpawnStone(int i)
{
    if(actualTime - rememberTime > differenceTime)
    {
        rememberTime = actualTime;
        lcd.setCursor(i,1);
        lcd.write(byte(2));
        lcd.setCursor(i+1,1);
        lcd.write(byte(9));
        SpawnStone(i-1);
    }
}
```

but it just made my stones appear at starting frame like this
 [:(](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfkfp.png)

Comment: You should at least share with us a minimum part of your code so we know what you are doing wrong.

Comment: @KamilCuk +1, my bad

Comment: create a timer based on the `millis()` method: https://learn.adafruit.com/multi-tasking-the-arduino-part-1/using-millis-for-timing

Comment: @Andy I already tried, but it seems for is still not blocked. Code based on that timer sometimes shows stone on floor in random place when happends "lucky frame" but not works as i want.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

// punktacja
int score = 0;
int lastScore = 0;

// czy gracz jeszcze gra
bool isPlaying = false;

// zmienna do lcd clear po zwycięstwie
bool blocker = true;

int buttonPin = 6;
int buttonState = 0;

// Obliczanie czasu do spawnu obstacli
long actualTime = 0;
long rememberTime = 0;
long differenceTime = 100;

int checkScore;

int stonePosition;

byte dino[8] = {
  0b01111,
  0b01111,
  0b00111,
  0b10110,
  0b11111,
  0b01010,
  0b01010,
  0b01011
};

byte stoneDown[8] = {
  0b00000,
  0b00100,
  0b01110,
  0b01110,
  0b01110,
  0b11111,
  0b11111,
  0b11111
};

byte clear[8] = {
  0b00000,
  0b00000,
  0b00000,
  0b00000,
  0b00000,
  0b00000,
  0b00000,
  0b00000
};


void setup() {
  
  Serial.begin(9600);
  
  checkScore = 0;
  
  pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.setCursor(11, 0);
  lcd.print("s:");
  
  rememberTime = millis();
  
  differenceTime = 100;
  
  lcd.createChar(0, dino);
  lcd.createChar(2, stoneDown);
  lcd.createChar(9, clear);
  
  stonePosition = 15;
}

void loop() {

  
  //Obliczanie czasu
  
  actualTime = millis();
  
  
  
  // Odczyt z guzika
  
  buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

  
  
  //Główna pętla gry
  
  if(isPlaying == false)    
  {
      
    
    // Dodatkowy poziom trudności
  
    if(score >= 1 && score <= 99)
    {
        differenceTime = 100;
    }
  
    if(score >= 100 && score <= 199)
    {
        differenceTime = 50;
        lcd.setCursor(2, 0);
        lcd.print("Faster!");
    }
  
    if(score >= 200 && score <= 299)
    {
        differenceTime = 30;
        lcd.setCursor(2, 0);
        lcd.print("FASTER!");
    }
    
    
    
    // Obsługa guzika
    
    if(buttonState == HIGH)
    {
      JumpDino();
    }
    
    else if (buttonState == LOW)
    {
      SpawnDino();
    }
    
    
    
    // Spawn kamieni
    
    if(actualTime - rememberTime >= differenceTime)
    {
        rememberTime = actualTime;
        stonePosition--;
        SpawnStone(stonePosition);
        if(stonePosition < 0)
        {
           stonePosition = 15;
        }
    }
      
    
    
    // Punktacja
    
    score = millis() / 100;
    lcd.setCursor(13, 0);
    lcd.print(score);
  }
  
  
  //LCD Clear po wygranej
  
  if(score == 301 && blocker == true)
  {
    blocker = false;
    lcd.clear();
  }
  
  
  
  //Informacja o zwycięstwie lub porażce
  
  if(stonePosition == 0 && buttonState == LOW)
  {
    isPlaying = true;
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("YOU LOST!");
    return;
  }
  
  if(score > 300)
  {
    isPlaying = true;
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("YOU WON!");
    return;
  }
}


// Dinozaur na dole lub u góry

void SpawnDino()
{
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.write(byte(0));
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.write(byte(9));
}

void JumpDino()
{
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.write(byte(0));
    if(stonePosition != 0)
    {
        lcd.setCursor(0,1);
        lcd.write(byte(9));
    }
}


// Spawn kamieni - funkcja

int SpawnStone(int i)
{
    lcd.setCursor(i,1);
    lcd.write(byte(2));
    lcd.setCursor(i+1,1);
    lcd.write(byte(9));
}
```

I did this that way for all time travellers. Hope you enjoy :)